# Set wrapping priority between primary and nested flex containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a [flexbox within a flexbox (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/20sLc5hs/):

The problem is that the items in the left div start to wrap earlier than necessary (the left div still has room to shrink).

The inner flexbox should only wrap after the outer flexbox has wrapped - as long as there is still space for the outer flexbox, the inner flexbox should not wrap and the outer flexbox should shrink, instead.

I tried to give `.b_row` a width of 100%, but that didn't work.

```css
.m {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.l_1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.r_1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.b_1 {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.b_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.b_item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=m>
  <div class=l_1>
    <div class=b_1>
      Left text
      <div class=b_row>
        <div class=b_item>Item 1
          <br>
          <input class=datepicker type=text size=10>
        </div>
        <div class=b_item>Item 2
          <br>
          <input class=datepicker type=text size=10>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class=r_1>Right Item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can control the wrapping behaviour using flex-basis in the inner elements.

(Solution without media queries)

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#right {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

#o1 {
  width: 400px;
}

#o2 {
  width: 300px;
}

#o3 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="o1">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="left">Left 1</div>
    <div class="left">Left 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>

<div class="outer" id="o2">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="left">Left 1</div>
    <div class="left">Left 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>

<div class="outer" id="o3">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="left">Left 1</div>
    <div class="left">Left 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly media queries will give you more control - especially when it comes to spacing elements apart from each other. I could only take it so far using CSS grid without media queries...

More about that here:
https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/

and the basics:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-template-columns/

[image: Resize demonstration gif]

```
<div class=m>
  <div class=l_1>
    <div class=b_1>
      Left text
      <div class=b_row>
        <div class=b_item>Item 1
          <br>
          <input class=datepicker type=text size=10>
        </div>
        <div class=b_item>Item 2
          <br>
          <input class=datepicker type=text size=10>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=r_1>Right Item</div>
</div>
```

```
.m {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.l_1 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.r_1 {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
}

.b_1 {
  padding: 1em;
  /*border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #febb02;
    border-color: #e2aa11;
  background-color: <? e($_COLORS['emph']);
  ?>;
  border: 1px solid <? e($_COLORS['emph_dark']);
  ?>;*/
}

.b_row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 2.2em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.b_item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.b_item input {
  width: 90%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z8swumkh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a media query to control the wrapping behavior of the inner flex container.

Instead of this:

```
.b_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Try something along these lines:

```
.b_row {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  width: 100%;
}

@media ( max-width: 300px ) {
   .b_row { flex-wrap: wrap; }
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/20sLc5hs/1/)

Comment: A good workaround, but still a workaround - I cannot believe that this is not possible in CSS...

Comment: I don't think it's a technical challenge for CSS. It's more like: *How is the browser supposed to know your preferred sequence for wrapping among different containers?* From the browser's perspective, it's arbitrary.

Comment: Also, different elements have different characteristics. For instance, input elements have an inherent minimum width. And what if there's content inside? Then what? I don't think my answer is a workaround. That's why media queries exist.

Comment: Well, if there is no way to tell the browser the preferred sequence for wrapping, then CSS is broken and we have to rely on workarounds - but that does not change the fact.

Comment: I agree with MB. It is up to the designer or engineer to delegate content hierarchy to the browser. The natural way html flows has never changed, just the way we tell it to has.

Comment: Also note: It's 2022, and there isn't a program yet that can properly translate a flat prototype into a semantic, functioning html page.

Answer (score 0):

using a media query to control the wrapping behavior. Certainly, media queries will give you more control - especially when it comes to spacing elements apart from each other. check the code

```css
body{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.m {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.l_1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.r_1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.b_1 {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.b_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.b_item {
  flex: 1;
}

.b_item .datepicker{
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  margin:0px 10px 0 0;
}

.b_item:last-child .datepicker{
  margin-right:0;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .m, .b_row{
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  
  .b_item .datepicker{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0px 10px;
  }
  .r_1, .l_1{
      margin:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=m>
  <div class=l_1>
    <div class=b_1>
      Left text
      <div class=b_row>
        <div class=b_item>Item 1
          <br>
          <input class=datepicker type=text size=10>
        </div>
        <div class=b_item>Item 2
          <br>
          <input class=datepicker type=text size=10>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class=r_1>Right Item</div>
</div>
```